# Dynamic link - Firebase - 400 error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I am using dynamic link feature in my Android native project to share the organization profile and organization data like event, news etc. The long link and short links are generated successfully. If I share the link using Whats app, it is opening correctly from my mobile and other mobile devices.

But, if I share the link using Facebook app, Facebook is displaying 400 error. The same happens with email client also. Please let me know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the URL. I was passing the callback URL instead of the original URL.

```
FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().createDynamicLink()
.setLink(Uri.parse(link))
.setDynamicLinkDomain(Myapp.getDynamicLinkDomain())
.buildShortDynamicLink()
```